# redefine a virtual method in each derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

I found quite a few similar posts but none clearly answered my question so here it is:

Let's say I have a class Country that instantiates an object of the class City and the latter has two subclasses House and Station.
In the class City, I declare a `virtual void method color()` which colors the houses and not the stations. And only the class `House` has a `color` attribute.
I redefine this method in my House subclass:

```
void color() override
{ // color my house 
 color_ = blue;
}
```

At compile time if I call `city_.color()` (let's say that houses and stations are already instantiated in the country), I will get an error indicating that the `color()` method is not redefined in the station `subclass`. What should I do, since I only want to color the houses.
Should I redefine the `color()` method also in station but leave it empty?

So in others words: When declaring a virtual function in a parent class, does each subclass have to redefine it ?
Thanks !

here is a minimal code (no functional only an exemple):

```
struct Country {
    Country(Position const& country);

    void virtual setHouseColor(Color color);
};
struct City {
    City(Position const& country);

    void virtual setHouseColor(Color color);
};

struct House : public City{
    House(Position position);
    void setHouseColor(Color color)
    {
       color_ = color;
    }
    
    Color color_
};

class Station : public City{
    // doesn't override setHouseColor(Color color);
};

int main()
{
  City city;
  
  for (auto house : houses)
  {
    city.setHouseColor(red);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code (preferably a [mcve]) rather than trying to describe the code.

Comment: Please add code, as text, that illustrates your issue.  For example, there are three forms of inheritance:  public, protected and private.  You didn't describe that or the accessibility of the methods.

Comment: Nitpick: Reconsider your naming. Neither a house nor a station is a city (but both are buildings).

Comment: Sounds like you want house and station to share a single base class, except that one of the methods in the base class (`color`) doesn't make any sense in one of the derived classes (`station`). This is a classic violation of the Interface Segregation Principle. Consider breaking apart your base class into multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to redefine the function in each subclass, but you do need a definition in the base class (in this case `City`).

A dumb (but valid) default implementation would look like this:

```
class City {
City(Position const& country);

void virtual setHouseColor(Color color) { };
};
```

You may want to have a more intelligent default implementation depending on what you're trying to do.

Note that there is a scenario in which you would need all subclasses to implement the `setHouseColor` method, and that's if you declare it as "pure virtual":

```
class City {
City(Position const& country);

void virtual setHouseColor(Color color) = 0;
};
```

This would mark `City` as an "abstract" class, in which case every deriving class would be required to implement all declared pure virtual methods.

Both of these approaches illustrate an important property of C++: there is no checking for validity of class methods at runtime, so the compiler has to enforce some kind of guarantee that when a virtual method gets called, there will be a valid entry in the vtable.